# Why Ajax work only when the internet is disabled?

Tags: php, ajax

i'm setting up an Ajax code for the comments system and another one for sorting products, but it only works when i'm offline

i tried another browser but it's the same problem, and i found this error in the console but i don't see any mistake in my code: Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.

here's my code for sorting products:

```
   <script>  
   $(document).ready(function(){  
   $(document).on('change', '#choix', function() { 
       var choix = $(this).val();  
       var id = <?php echo intval($_GET['id']); ?>;
       $.ajax({  
            url:"../Ressources/sort_products.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{choix:choix,id:<?php echo intval($_GET['id']); ?>},  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#show_product').html(data);  
            } 
       });  
  });  
 });  
 </script>
```

and this is the code for the comments :

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#submit').click(function(){


 var id = <?php echo $id; ?>;
 var commentaire = $('#commentaire').val();

$.ajax({
url:"add_comment.php",
method:"POST",
data:'id='+id+'&commentaire='+commentaire,
success:function(data)
{

 $('#comment_form')[0].reset();
 alert("Votre commentaire a été ajouté");
 load_comment();

   }
 })
});

load_comment();

function load_comment()
{
var idp = <?php echo $id; ?>;
$.ajax({
url:"fetch_comment.php",
method:"POST",
data:{idp}, 
success:function(data)
{
$('#display_comment').html(data);
  }
});
}
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){

       var id = $(this).attr("id");
       $.ajax({  
            url:"../Ressources/delete_comment.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{id:id},  
            success:function(data){  
                   alert("Votre commentaire a été supprimé"); 
                    load_comment();
            } 
       });  
  });  


});
</script>
```

Comment: Open the browser inspector network tab (ctrl+shift+c in Firefox/Chrome) and look at the error you're getting

Comment: @glyph i copied the error i got below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are  using the slim build of jQuery, which  some things removed, Just download the regular (compressed or not) version of jQuery [here](https://jquery.com/download/) and include it in your project.

the slim version saves weight(file size of the normal version) by excluding the ajax and effects modules.

Comment: have you tried clearing your web browser cache or try using another web browser

Comment: what version of jquery are you using

Comment: i'm using jQuery v1.11.1

Comment: Try using version 1.5 or higher